# Android studio 2.2 gradle plugin for instant run error

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2, android-instant-run

I am using android studio 2.2 and getting the below error while trying to build the project
        **Error:Cause: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin cannot be cast to groovy.lang.GroovyObject**

```
    I added classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    in my top level gradle 

My project has 11 modules and compilesdk version is 23,buildtools version is 24.0.2
```

How can I build the fix the issues and build the project

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem。
“Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins... ”as the console reminders。
So you should check your buildscript{dependencies{}} in build.gradle file。
Like this：

```
dependencies {
   ......
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2'
    classpath 'com.xxx.gradle.sign:sign:0.2.0'
   ......
}
```

and I update the sign plugin from sign:0.2.0 to sign:0.1.0,then it's ok。So you should find the incompatible plugin and update it。